# Questions on Rails validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  validates_associated :books
end
```

From what I understand, this makes sure that the `books` associated with `Library` are valid books. Ie. this won't allow an invalid book to be associated with `Library`.

Questions:

1) Does `validates_associated :books` also ensure that `Library` has at least one book? If not, how do you do that? All the validators seem to work on fields of the model, but there aren't any fields of the `Library` model that reference `books`.

2) What does it mean that `This validation must not be used on both ends of an association. Doing so will lead to a circular dependency and cause infinite recursion.`? Does it mean that you shouldn't have `validates_associated :library` in the `Book` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question:** No, it does not ensure that. In order to ensure that you have at least one book:

```
validates :books, presence: true
```

**Second question:** Yes, that is correct. A library will try to validate its first book, that book will try to validate its library, which will in turn try to validate that same first book... and so on.

For more information on validations, check out the [Validations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).